# What process should be undertaken to get feedback from white-label clients?

Tags: feedback, analytics, quantitative-analysis

I'm currently working with a company that distrbutes their white-label product and I was wondering what is the best process in order to get feedback from clients in regards to how their customers are finding the ux?
My suggestion is to use analytical tools such as Hotjar and FullStory.

I want to appeal to their self-interest by reiterating that by using these tools, we get rich data that enables us to make improvements to the UX which will eventually benefits them because they use product

Are there alternatives ways to collect UX data from clients and how often should it done?

Your thoughts are appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is rating feature where possible to display to gain feedback about overall UX. Once I used `sticky smile face` on the left corner of the footer to pop-up but main idea was showing a 3 point-likert system which evaluates users like or dislike the product.

And the `textbook below of the like and dislike buttons` was good enough to get feedbacks about any state of the application except not capable of getting the exact state of users to assume which exact moment they felt the pain point.

Comment: That's a good idea but we want more qualitative data, I'm trying to brainstorm many ideas so I will include yours and try to get more ideas to implement. Thanks Erhan